# product ids separate with # on success page

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, orders, product-list, variables

I'm facing problem, need to show product ids separated with # on Magento success page

like:

shop_product_ids =‘#234#w475xk#5402#’;

How to handle it on Magento 1.9 success page.
Can anybody let me know how to make this loop and properly format ids separated with #

Comment: This question has been answered here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/260603/59701

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to the success page template `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/success.phtml` (for base theme)

Aafter `<?php if ($this->getOrderId()):?>` add:

```
    <?php
    $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($this->getOrderId());
    $items = $order->getAllVisibleItems(); // use getAllItems for ALL items, including simple products from configurable
    $productsIds = array();
    /** @var Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Item $item */
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        $productsIds[] = $item->getProductId(); // for SKU: $item->getProduct()->getSku();
    }
    $productsIdsString = implode('#', $productsIds);
    $productsIdsString = 'shop_product_ids = \'#' . $productsIdsString . '#;';

    echo '<h1>' . $productsIdsString . '</h1>'; // or do something else
    ?>
```

Items during checkout:

[image: checkout]

Result in debug:

[image: debug]

Result on success page:

[image: success page]

Comment: goos answer Siarhey Uchukhlebau,can u tell me what debugger you have use

Comment: @AmitBera xDebug with phpStorm

Comment: very good explaination @SiarheyUchukhlebau