# Summary of purchase on the success page

Tags: magento-1.9, product, cart, orders, purchase-order

I wanted to summarize the purchase on the success page, as if it were a cart with all the products that the user bought, with the image, product name, quantity and price of it. From the code below I can see how many products are in the cart, but I can not get them and assemble the HTML portion of this summary.Thanks in advance.

```
$order = Mage::getSingleton('sales/order'); 
$order->loadByIncrementId(Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastRealOrderId());
$_items = $order->getAllItems();
echo count($_items);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code.

```
<?php 
    $order_id = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastRealOrderId(); 
    $order_details = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($order_id); 
?>
    <table>
     <tr> 
        <th><?php echo $this->__('Description') ?></th
        <th><?php echo $this->__('Description') ?></th>
        <th><?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?></th>
        <th><?php echo $this->__('Unit Price') ?></th>
    </tr>

    <?php foreach($order_details->getAllVisibleItems() as $item): 
    $configItem = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', $item->getSku());
    ?> 
        <tr>
            <td><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($configItem, 'small_image')->resize(200); ?>" width="200" height="200" class="media-object img-responsive" alt="<?php echo $this->getImageLabel($configItem, 'small_image'); ?>"/></td>
            <td><?php echo $item->getName() ?></td>
            <td><?php echo round($item->getQtyOrdered(), 0) ?></td>
            <td><?php echo Mage::helper("core")->currency($item->getPrice()) ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach ?>
        </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Override */app/code/Mage/Checkout/Block/Onepage/Success.php* with your local copy. and edit the following method below. This will include the items in the success block.

```
protected function _prepareLastOrder()
{
    $orderId = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastOrderId();
    if ($orderId) {
        $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);
        if ($order->getId()) {
            $isVisible = !in_array($order->getState(),
                Mage::getSingleton('sales/order_config')->getInvisibleOnFrontStates());
            $this->addData(array(
                'is_order_visible' => $isVisible,
                'view_order_id' => $this->getUrl('sales/order/view/', array('order_id' => $orderId)),
                'print_url' => $this->getUrl('sales/order/print', array('order_id'=> $orderId)),
                'can_print_order' => $isVisible,
                'can_view_order'  => Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn() && $isVisible,
                'order_id'  => $order->getIncrementId(),
                'all_items' => $order->getAllItems(),
            ));
        }
    }
}
```

You should notice the line **'all_items' => $order->getAllItems(),**

And then in your success.phtml file, you can access all of the items in an order.

```
$items = array();
foreach ($this->getAllItems() as $item) {
    $items[]['id'] = $item->getProductId();
    $items[]['price'] = $item->getPrice();
    $items[]['quantity'] = $item->getQtyOrdered();
}
```